# Subtracting value from parent table with SUM(value from child table)

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have 2 tables, `tblBasicInfo` and `tblPayment`.

Relationship is 1 to many,  where `tblBasicInfo` is on the 1 side, and `tblPayment` is on the `many` side.

*Relationship is optional and that is the problem.*

I need to subtract value of certain field from parent table with sum of certain fields from child table *that match certain criteria.*

If there are no records in child table that fulfill the criteria then this should be represented with zero ( `data from parent table - 0` ).

*I apologize if this is not crystal clear, English is not my native and I am not experienced enough to know how to properly describe the problem.*

It would be best to demonstrate what I mean with a small example:

We shall start from table schema:

```
tblBasicInfo: #ID, TotalPrice (double)

tblPayment: #P_ID, $ID, Amount (double), IsPaid (bool)
```

Here is the content for parent table `tblBasicInfo`:

```
ID | TotalPrice

 1 | 100

 2 | 150

 3 | 200

 4 | 250
```

Here is the content for child table `tblPayment`:

```
P_ID | ID | IsPaid | Amount

  1  |  1 |  true   | 50

  2  |  1 |  false  | 25

  3  |  2 |  false  | 100

  4  |  2 |  false  | 25

  5  |  3 |  true   | 200
```

This is what I have accomplished on my own:

```
SELECT tblBasicInfo.ID, 
    ( tblBasicInfo.TotalPrice - sum(tblPayment.Amount) ) AS [Difference]
    FROM tblBasicInfo, tblPayment 
    WHERE ( tblBasicInfo.ID = tblPayment.ID )
    GROUP BY tblBasicInfo.TotalPrice, tblPayment.IsPaid 
    HAVING ( tblPayment.IsPaid = TRUE )  --this is the criteria I talked above
    ORDER BY tblBasicInfo.ID;
```

This is what I get from the above query:

```
ID | Difference

 1 | 50
 3 | 0
 .
 .
 .
```

I need to get the following result:

```
ID | Difference

 1 | 50
 2 | 150     -- does not meet the criteria ( IsPayed = false )
 3 | 0
 4 | 250     -- no records in child table
 .
 .
 .
```

*I apologize for imperfect title of the question, but I really did not know how to describe this problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on SQL Server, but you can achieve same in other RDMS you can achieve this in probably more than one way here I presented two solutions I found that first solution performs better than second

```
SELECT ti.id,MAX(totalprice) - ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN is_payed = ((0)) THEN 0 ELSE amount END),0) amount
FROM tblbasicinfo ti LEFT OUTER JOIN  tblpayment tp ON ti.id = tp.p_id
GROUP BY ti.id 

--OR 

SELECT id,totalprice-ISNULL((SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM tblpayment tp 
WHERE  ti.id = tp.p_id AND is_payed = ((1))
GROUP BY id),0) AS reconsile
 FROM tblbasicinfo ti
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE tblBasicInfo (id INT IDENTITY(1,1),totalprice MONEY)

CREATE TABLE tblPayment (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), P_ID INT ,is_payed BIT,amount MONEY)

INSERT INTO tblbasicinfo

VALUES(100),(150),(200),(250)

INSERT INTO tblpayment(p_id,is_payed,amount)
VALUES(1,((1)),50),(1,((0)),25),(2,((0)),100),(2,((0)),25),(3,((1)),200)
```

Comment: I have chosen the second option. One note for the future readers, **and an important one:** `ISNULL` function is not the same in SQL Server and MS Access, in MS Access use `NZ` instead! Upvoted and officially accepted. Thank you. Best regards until next time!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  select a.Id,(a.TotalPrice-payment.paid) as Difference  from tblBasicInfo a
  left join 
  (

   select sum(Amount) as paid,Id
   from 
   tblPayment
     group by Id
      where IsPaid =1)payment
    on a.Id=payment.Id
```

Comment: OK, I have tried it and it works. I just ask you to help me with the following: for case when there are no records in child table, `Difference` is `NULL`. I need it to be `TotalPrice` instead. I have managed to do this by changing `(a.TotalPrice-payment.paid)` into `NZ(a.TotalPrice-payment.paid, a.TotalPrice)` but I am interested to know if there is a better way. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: you can try this :,(a.TotalPrice-isnull(payment.paid,0)) as Difference  for difference.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. The reason I accepted other one is that it is is easier for me to understand it. Thank you for your help. Best regards until next time.

Answer (score 0):

(minor correction - IsPaid rather than IsPayed)
This isn't tested or anything it is just to point you in the right direction hopefully.
You want to use a left join and then check to see if amount is null in your calculation of `difference`

```
SELECT
    bi.ID, 
    ( bi.TotalPrice - sum(IIF(p.Amount is null,0,p.Amount)) ) AS [Difference]
    FROM tblBasicInfo bi,
        left join tblPayment p
            on p.id = bi.id
            and p.IsPaid = 1
    GROUP BY bi.ID, bi.TotalPrice
    ORDER BY bi.ID;
```